# Video controls default to bottom of device

Tags: android, video, controls

I am working on an app and I have video stacked evenly on top of an image. You can see that in the attached photo. Why do the video player controls default to the bottom of the device like in the photo? I want to move them over top just the video if possible. My layout for this screen is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mobile_vforum_bg"
    >
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/vidPlayer"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="240dip">
    </VideoView>
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/slideHolder"
        android:layout_width="320dip" 
        android:layout_height="240dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
     </WebView>
     <ListView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/slideList"
        android:background="#000000">
     </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Uploaded Image of phone]

anyone know if I can move the video controls on top of the video?

Comment: According to the docs for `VideoView`... it "takes care of computing its measurement from the video so that it can be used in any layout manager". Rather than setting the width/height in `dip`s have you tried simply using `wrap_content`?

Comment: I tried setting VideoView width/height to wrap content and I get the same behavior. It's going to be a loooong day of googling I can tell

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is make sure to set an anchor view for the controls and to make sure the anchor view doesn't take up the whole screen. For example, here's a sample layout (incomplete, but gets the point across):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preview_video_container_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <VideoView 
            android:id="@+id/preview_video_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code when you set the media controller, you would do the following:

```
    mPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.preview_video_view);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mPreview);
```

The key is that the inner linear layout has wrap content for the height so it doesn't take up the entire screen. This will end up showing the controls right under the video. If you want to do something even more funky like have the controls on top of the video itself (and have then appear/disappear), then I believe you would have to create your own controls and lay them out with the video view.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the fact you're using a FrameLayout and there's not enough room on the display to display everything. Is there a reason you need to use exact pixel specifications for your size? You should always avoid those if possible because in android you never know what size of screen your app is going to be running on.

Comment: well 320x240 are the size of my videos. What are my other options?

Comment: That's understandable then. Have you tried using any of the other layouts though?